# Webpack - How to require result file in base html (best practice)

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, single-page-application

I just started using Webpack for my SPA and I have a question. How do I require the result bundle/file in my HTML? Should I just use the  tag or is there a better practice for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can automatically include all JavaScript and CSS bundles using [HTML Webpack Plugin](https://nodei.co/npm/html-webpack-plugin/).

## Example

To install the plugin you need to run `npm install html-webpack-plugin --save-dev` in your project directory.

In the following example plugin will read source HTML file and automatically append available CSS files in `head` and all JavaScript bundles just before the end of `body`. It plays nicely with [ExtractTextPlugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/extract-text-webpack-plugin). If you have more bundle chunks, they'll be appended appropriately as well.

As a bonus you can use [any template](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-plugin#writing-your-own-templates) engine if you want to dynamically change or generate parts of your HTML file. Out of the box it supports EJS template engine with possibility to use any other [via loaders](https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin/blob/master/docs/template-option.md).

```js
var webpack = require("webpack");
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/js/entry',                   // Source JavaScript file
    output: {
        path: './bin/',                        // Output directory
        filename: "./js/bundle.js"             // Result JavaScript file
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html',      // Source HTML file
            filename: './index.html'           // Result HTML file
        }),
    ]
};
```

It's worth noting that HTML Webpack Plugin have a lot of features to play with, including **minifying**, filtering chunks, adding file hash to URLs to prevent caching... You can learn about those and many more in [documentation](https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin/blob/master/docs/template-option.md).

Answer (score 1):

You can look my starter seed with angular2 + webpack. All files has been in build directory(app.js, vendor.js, polyfills.js) + maps

[Link to webpack.config.js](https://github.com/vitalics/Angular2StarterSeedWebpack/blob/master/webpack.config.js)

Answer (score 1):

Webpack is a module bundler. It will bundle your entire SPA in a single or multiple javascript bundles according to your webpack configuration. Now we need to import these js bundles inside our HTML code and the only way to insert those things in our HTML is to use script tag. So you import them in your html like this :

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

So yes, this is the best practice.